# Elegant porting of lambda expressions in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, lambda

Since lambda expressions require GCC version > 4.4: what is the most elegant or fastest (yet not too 'dirty') way of porting code containing a couple of lambda expressions with reference-bound variables to pre-C++0x code?

Can this be done in a semi automated way using templates/macros?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look at [boost::lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/lambda.html). This should do what you are looking for.

Comment: +1. I used boost::lambda a little, but I found it quite awkward in some ways. You can't directly use methods on the lambda args. For example you can't do `sort(v.begin(), v.end(), _1.size() < _2.size())` but you can do `sort(v.begin(), v.end(), f(_1) < f(_2) )`. Maybe there is something I missed ...

Comment: As of Boost 1.47 (which is currently in beta and will be released within the next couple weeks), Boost.Lambda is officially deprecated and replaced by [Boost.Phoenix v3](http://beta.boost.org/libs/phoenix/index.html), so Boost.Phoenix is a better recommendation at this point.

Comment: @Aaron : Boost.Phoenix contains lazy [wrappers for all standard library containers and algorithms](http://beta.boost.org/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/stl.html), so that would look like `sort(v.begin, v.end(), size(_1) < size(_2))` without any additional code.

Comment: @ildjarn: I did not realize this up to now. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer: I'm linking to my own site.)

About a year ago, I put a few useful macros on a [a blog post of mine](http://www.aaronmcdaid.com/2010/07/yalm-yet-another-lamdba-macro-for-c.html). I don't know how portable it is, and it's pretty limited. But for simple expressions, it works well.

Note that I haven't found much use for it myself, so it can't be that good :-)

```
sort(vs.begin(), vs.end(),
YALM(bool,vector<int>&,vector<int>&,return l.size() < r.size()  )
);
```